Parsing formulas efficiently using regex and Polars
I am trying to parse a series of mathematical formulas and need to extract variable names efficiently using Polars in Python.
Regex support in Polars seems to be limited, particularly with look-around assertions.
Is there a simple, efficient way to parse symbols from formulas?
Here's the snippet of my code:
import re
import polars as pl

# Define the regex pattern
FORMULA_DECODER = r"\b[A-Za-z][A-Za-z_0-9_]*\b(?!\()"
# \b          # Assert a word boundary to ensure matching at the beginning of a word
# [A-Za-z]    # Match an uppercase or lowercase letter at the start
# [A-Za-z0-9_]* # Match following zero or more occurrences of valid characters (letters, digits, or underscores)
# \b          # Assert a word boundary to ensure matching at the end of a word
# (?!\()      # Negative lookahead to ensure the match is not followed by an open parenthesis (indicating a function)

# Sample formulas
formulas = ["3*sin(x1+x2)+A_0",
            "ab*exp(2*x)"]

# expected result
pl.Series(formulas).map_elements(lambda formula: re.findall(FORMULA_DECODER, formula), return_dtype=pl.List(pl.String))
# Series: '' [list[str]]
# [
#   ["x1", "x2", "A_0"]
#   ["ab", "x"]
# ]

# Polars does not support this regex pattern
pl.Series(formulas).str.extract_all(FORMULA_DECODER)
# ComputeError: regex error: regex parse error:
#     \b[A-Za-z][A-Za-z_0-9_]*\b(?!\()
#                               ^^^
# error: look-around, including look-ahead and look-behind, is not supported

Edit
Here is a small benchmark:
import random
import string
import re
import polars as pl

def generate_symbol():
    """Generate random symbol of length 1-3."""
    characters = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase
    return ''.join(random.sample(characters, random.randint(1, 3)))

def generate_formula():
    """Generate random formula with 2-5 unique symbols."""
    op = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
    return ''.join([generate_symbol()+random.choice(op) for _ in range(random.randint(2, 6))])[:-1]


def generate_formulas(num_formulas):
    """Generate random formulas."""
    return [generate_formula() for _ in range(num_formulas)]

# Sample formulas
# formulas = ["3*sin(x1+x2)+(A_0+B)",
#             "ab*exp(2*x)"]

def parse_baseline(formulas):
    """Baseline serves as performance reference. It will not detect function names."""
    FORMULA_DECODER_NO_LOOKAHEAD = r"\b[A-Za-z][A-Za-z_0-9_]*\b\(?"
    return pl.Series(formulas).str.extract_all(FORMULA_DECODER_NO_LOOKAHEAD)

def parse_lookahead(formulas):
    FORMULA_DECODER = r"\b[A-Za-z][A-Za-z_0-9_]*\b(?!\()"
    return pl.Series(formulas).map_elements(lambda formula: re.findall(FORMULA_DECODER, formula), return_dtype=pl.List(pl.String))

def parse_no_lookahead_and_filter(formulas):
    FORMULA_DECODER_NO_LOOKAHEAD = r"\b[A-Za-z][A-Za-z_0-9_]*\b\(?"
    return (
        pl.Series(formulas)
        .str.extract_all(FORMULA_DECODER_NO_LOOKAHEAD)
        # filter for matches not containing an open parenthesis
        .list.eval(pl.element().filter(~pl.element().str.contains("(", literal=True)))
    )

formulas = generate_formulas(1000)
%timeit parse_lookahead(formulas)
%timeit parse_no_lookahead_and_filter(formulas)
%timeit parse_baseline(formulas)
# 10.7 ms ± 387 μs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
# 1.31 ms ± 76.1 μs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
# 708 μs ± 6.43 μs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)


Could you drop the negative lookahead and then filter the matches afterwards (exclude any match containing an open parenthesis)?

Parsing without lookahead and then filtering the elements seems to be pretty close to the performance of just using str.extract_all. The additional filter is pretty cheap. Thank you.

Just to note why this is: Polars uses the underlying Rust regex library. https://github.com/rust-lang/regex - "lacks several features that are not known how to implement efficiently"

That's true. The Polars documentation mentions polars.Series.str.extract_all expects a regular expression pattern, compatible with the regex crate.
The regex crate does not support look-around assertions and so does Polars.
Personally, I would prefer having a more readable version like "extract_all(pattern)" available. Unfortunately, this is not the possible in this case.

As mentioned in the comment, you could drop the negative lookahead and optionally include the open parenthesis in the match. In a post-processing step, you could then filter out any matches containing an open parenthesis (using pl.Series.list.eval).
This could look as follows.
# avoid negative lookahead and optionally match open parenthesis
FORMULA_DECODER_NO_LOOKAHEAD = r"\b[A-Za-z][A-Za-z_0-9_]*\b\(?"

(
    pl.Series(formulas)
    .str.extract_all(FORMULA_DECODER_NO_LOOKAHEAD)
    # filter for matches not containing an open parenthesis
    .list.eval(pl.element().filter(~pl.element().str.contains("(", literal=True)))
)

shape: (2,)
Series: '' [list[str]]
[
    ["x1", "x2", "A_0"]
    ["ab", "x"]
]

